# Source-level transformation in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm trying to write a sphinx extension that performs a source-level transformation, but I don't know how to actually change the output file.

My extension looks something like this:

```
def my_source_handler(app, docname, source):
    import re
    print 'test'
    source = [re.sub("foo", "bar", source[0])]
    return source

def setup(app):
    app.connect('source-read', my_source_handler)
    app.add_config_value('my_source_handler_include', True, False)
```

However, when I add the module to the extensions list and `build html`, it prints the 'test' but does not actually change the "foo"s to "bar"s in the output HTML file.

The [Sphinx documentation](http://sphinx-doc.org/extdev/appapi.html#event-source-read) is a little vague, saying, "You can process the contents and replace this item to implement source-level transformations" with regards to the source argument.

The problem is I'm not sure how I'm supposed to go about replacing the source argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually after a little digging I figured it out, you're supposed to replace the contents of the first (and only) element of `source`, not replace `source` itself, so like:

```
def my_source_handler(app, docname, source):
    import re
    print 'test'
    source[0] = re.sub("foo", "bar", source[0])
```